# What are the ways to write Mockito Junits for Rowmapper class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

What are the possible ways to write Mockito Junit test cases for Rowmapper class? Without interacting with DB how we can do mocking data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple plain JUnit Test with the help of mockito like this (pseudo code):

```
class YourMapperTest {

    @Test
    void testMapRow() throws Exception {
        ResultSet resultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);
        when(resultSet.getString("yourStringColumn")).thenReturn("Hello World");
        when(resultSet.getLong("yourLongColumn")).thenReturn(1067L);

        YourDTO dto = new YourRowMapper().mapRow(resultSet, 0);
        assertEquals("some expected string", dto.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use ResultSet i need use DB. When i am doing insert and delete activities it is impacting on my dev db.i have to avoid these modifications on my dev db.